# Unity prefab as an object in inspector asking for attaching object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am initiating prefabs as objects and then trying to do something using these objects that have those prefabs. However, in the inspector, its asking to attach objects that are actually already attached via code.

**Code**

```
public float hitspeed=2f;
public GameObject target, mytarget;
public GameObject arrow,myarrow;

//Use this for initialization
void Start (){
    myarrow = Instantiate(arrow, new Vector3(0.02f, -3.98f, 0), transform.rotation);
    mytarget = Instantiate(target, new Vector3(-0.06435323f, 2.325303f, 0f), transform.rotation);
}
```

**Inspector**

[image: inspector]

**Error**

> [06:34:34] UnassignedReferenceException: The variable arrow of knife has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the arrow variable of the knife script in the inspector.
>
> [06:34:39] UnassignedReferenceException: The variable myarrow of knife has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the myarrow variable of the knife script in the inspector.

Comment: Please do not post *images* of code...

Comment: If the images are correct, you never assigned an objet to arrow so, when you try to create myarrow you get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

With your object selected so you can see the inspector shown in the image

Go to your Project window, find your prefab.

Drag it to the the inspector where it says "none."

You can also click the little target/circle next to "none" and choose from a list.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you seem to have assigned `myarrow` and `mytarget`, however, you have instantiated them using `target` and `arrow`. You have set `target` using the gui, but not `arrow`. You must also set `arrow`.

In general, and to quote from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976448/1456253):

> [`arrow` and `target` have] to be a prefab that you've already created in the Editor and
>   dragged/dropped onto the Inspector window for this object.
>
> Ensure you:
>
> 1. Created a prefab
> 2. Selected this object in the Editor, so the Inspector appears
> 3. Drag/dropped that prefab onto the "arrow"/"target" field in the Inspector